# Anylogic: Agent cannot be cast to class

Tags: anylogic

I watched the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2BAv6DFPhU
My agent type is Product. I'm not sure what I can do to solve this error. Thank you for your help!

The error message showed up as follows:

Exception during discrete event execution:

class com.anylogic.engine.Agent cannot be cast to class tutorialkanban.Product (com.anylogic.engine.Agent and tutorialkanban.Product are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.anylogic.engine.Agent cannot be cast to class tutorialkanban.Product (com.anylogic.engine.Agent and tutorialkanban.Product are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

```
at tutorialkanban.kanban_logic$3.onExit(kanban_logic.java:1)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Source.q(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Source.q(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Source$1.onEnter(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Enter.c(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Enter.c(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Enter$1.onExit(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer.c(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer.c(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer$1.onExit(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.c(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$1.b(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.receiveImmediately(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.a(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.action(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.execute(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$e.execute(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.i(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.nm(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.n(Unknown Source)

at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$e.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: you probably didn't define your agent to be a product in your process modeling library blocks

Comment: Most likely is kind of the 'reverse' of what Felipe says: your process blocks have been set with agent Type `Product` but your `Source` block is creating standard agents (of type `Agent`), so the downstream blocks can't 'see the agent as a Product' (in Java terms cast the object of type `Agent` to type `Product`).

Comment: Thank you, guys! I forgot to set one of the blocks agent to Product. Now, it's solved! Thanks again!