# Error code while accessing custom parameter values from excel file

Tags: anylogic, agent

I am tryig to build a discrete agent based model.
I have a set of agents with custom parameters, these parameters are loaded via an excel file (this part works, I can view the agents). All agents are created at once at the model start-up.

Now I want the agents to move through the system based on these parameters.
I have build a dummy-model with a `selectOutputIn` and two `SelectOutputOut` blocks and a `function`.
I want the agent to move to `selectOutputOutBasic` if a string-parameter has a certain value.

The function code is:

```
if (agent.variation == "Basic")
    return selectOutputOutBasic;
else return selectOutputOut;
```

Anylogic builds the model, but when I try to run it, I get the following error corde:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
class com.anylogic.engine.Agent cannot be cast to class test.Order (com.anylogic.engine.Agent and test.Order are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.anylogic.engine.Agent cannot be cast to class test.Order (com.anylogic.engine.Agent and test.Order are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at test.Main$1.choice(Main.java:1)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.SelectOutputIn.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.SelectOutputIn.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.SelectOutputIn$1.outputBlock(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.action(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$b.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.m(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.jj(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Don't think I can be much help with this one. I found this SO post with some potentially useful comments if you want to check it out. [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66558476/11342997)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, those who can read have an advantage...

I found the solution to my problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034256/anylogic-custom-agent-not-loading), thanks @ Dat Boi!

> Try going to the service properties. Under the "Advanced" tab, is
> `Agent Type` selected as "MyAgent" or as "Agent"? Similarly, go to the
> source properties and check the tab `Agent` and make sure "MyAgent" is
> selected.
>
> [image]